# Routing in laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel-4

I using the laravel framework of php for development.I done these following
     steps

1. I define `Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');` in route file and then define `Route::get('user/pingme', 'UserController@pingme');`
2. When i make a get call to pingme function, it was not working .I was getting the `response code is 200` but code inside that `pingme` function was not working and i do not know why.
3. then i changed it to `Route::post('user/pingme', 'UserController@pingme');` it was working fine as needed.
4. then what i did is, removed `Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');` and make again get route to ping me function and make get call and it starts working fine .

so this is any bug in framework(rare thing) or i am missing something(probably yes)? Help me out....

Comment: are you sure you need to use `Route::resource()` in this case? It's only used together with Resource Controllers.

Comment: yes in user controller ,i an creating storing user ,updating user.

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: here is the [link for route](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:3edb) and [link for controller](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:3edc)

Comment: did you run `composer dump-autoload` after changing the `routes.php` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route file works as follows:-

1. if you have wrote a mapping for controller only, then it needs to come at the bottom of all other route mapping otherwise your program controller will pick route from user controller only and will redirect to UserController.
   so the right order of all routes is:-

   Route::get('user/pingme', 'UserController@pingme');

   Route::post('user/logout', 'UserController@logout')->before('auth');

   Route::resource('user', 'UserController');

OR

```
 Route::post('user/logout', 'UserController@logout')->before('auth');

 Route::get('user/pingme', 'UserController@pingme');

 Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your route file, the order of the routes needs to be as follows:

```
Route::get('user/pingme', 'UserController@pingme');

Route::post('user/logout', 'UserController@logout')->before('auth');

Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

If `Route::resource('user', 'UserController')` comes before the other routes, the `GET` request to `user/pingme` will be handled by `show` method inside of `UserController`, because it is how Resourceful Controllers work. So, the `Route::resource` for `user` needs to come after all other routes with `user/` prefix.